# HP Laptop Boot Issues

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, hp-pavilion, hp-laptop

I have a HP Pavilion dv7 laptop which has recently been taken apart to resolve overheating issues, new thermal paste was applied and everything seems fine.

Now, when booting the laptop it refuse's to boot with the dvd/cd drive installed, the power button will blink once and nothing happens, upon removing the the drive and trying again it boots as normal.

Possible faulty drive, bearing in mind the laptop booted fine before disassembly. Is there any way to install the drive but not have the laptop detect it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the boot order. When your laptop starts, hold down the button to open the BIOS config (typically F2 or F12, depends on your computer).

Use the keyoard to navigate, the actual keys to use are listed at the bottom of the screen. Find a "Boot" or "Startup" tab (or something like that, again, depends on your computer). Look for something called "Boot Order": it should be a list of the devices installed on your computer. Use the keys to move the hard drive to the top, or at least above the optical drive. Then save config and exit.

I can't give you the exact keys to use or the exact place to look at because it is specific to your computer model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already checked the boot order. However it is now fixed, I had connected the drive to the wrong socket on the motherboard, it was in the secondary HDD socket! I changed it over and now its working!